# Why is there a yellow mark on the `or` in line 11?

Tags: python

Also, everything function normally - I'm just concerned with the error.

```py
def name_scan(a, list1 = [], x = 0):
    if a.count(" ") > 1 or a.count(" ") < 1:
        return False
    name_first = a[0] + a[1:a.find(" ")]
    name_last = a[a.find(" ")+1] + a[a.find(" ")+2:]
    if len(name_first) < 3 or len(name_first) > 60 or len(name_last) < 3 or len(name_last) > 60:
        return False
    else:
        for b in a:
            x += 1
            if b.isdigit() or b in ("`~!@#$%^&*()_+{|}:?><,./;'[]\=-" or '"'):        # This Line #
                return False
            elif x == len(a):
                name_first = a.upper()[0] + a.lower()[1:a.find(" ")]
                name_last = a.upper()[a.find(" ")+1] + a.lower()[a.find(" ")+2:]
                list1.append(name_first + " " + name_last)
                return list1[list1.index(name_first + " " + name_last)]
```

[image: Visual Reference]

Comment: Did you try hovering your mouse over the `or` and seeing if there's a tooltip?

Comment: (There are a lot of bugs and weird, pointless things in this code, such as the mutable default `list1`, the misuse of `or` in the *non*-squigglied case on that line, the weird string concatenation in the initialization of `name_first` and `name_last`, etc., but the `or` with the squiggly line on it seems fine.)

Comment: `Anomalous backslash in string: '\='. String constant might be missing an r prefix.pylint(anomalous-backslash-in-string)`
This was the error from the yellow backlash.  Not really sure what it means though.

Comment: @EvanSchwartzentruber: [My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61720646/364696) fixes that problem as well. You wanted to search for a backslash or an equals sign, but a literal like `'\='` is imprecise; you *might* mean backslash followed by equals, or you might mean "unnecessarily escaped equals". Older Python silently treated it as the former, more recent Python will warn, and it will eventually become an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
("`~!@#$%^&*()_+{|}:?><,./;'[]\=-" or '"')
```

unconditionally evaluates to:

```
"`~!@#$%^&*()_+{|}:?><,./;'[]\=-"
```

as `or` resolves to the first operand if it's truthy, or the last operand otherwise, so your actual test ends up being:

```
b in "`~!@#$%^&*()_+{|}:?><,./;'[]\=-"
```

ignoring the `'"'`. I suspect you wanted to allow any of those punctuation marks, so you really want to test:

```
b in "`~!@#$%^&*()_+{|}:?><,./;'[]\\=-\""
```

which includes the escaped quote in the set to test and escapes the backslash (so you explicitly accept an escaped backslash, rather than leaving ambiguity as to whether you were trying to escape the following equals sign).

**Update:** As it turns out, the warning you were seeing related to the ambiguously escaped equals sign; a literal like `"\="` triggers the warning, while `"\\="` (explicitly escaping the backslash) fixes it.

Comment: That's one of the multiple bugs in this code, but the yellow squigglies are on the *other* `or` on that line.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica: True. I wouldn't be surprised if the squigglied `or` was either caused indirectly by the problem I note, or complaining about line length style issues. The OP should say what the tooltip for it says to be sure.